# OAuth2 и AccountManager

Tags: java, android

Необходимо сделать OAuth2 авторизацию и я хочу привязать её к AccountManager'у. Может быть кто-то уже делал подобное?

Я тут кое-что набросал, хотелось бы узнать, в правильном направлении иду. Если нет то тогда может кто поделился бы более правильным решением. Ещё вычитал про AuthorizationCodeFlow от Google. Вроде как подходит и не для сервисов гугла, а и для сторонних. Может кто имел дело с ним?

```
public class AvestAuthenticator extends AbstractAccountAuthenticator implements Constants {

private Context context;

public AvestAuthenticator(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public Bundle editProperties(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, String accountType) {
    Log.d("logba", "AvestAuthenticator->editProperties : ");
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

@Override
public Bundle addAccount(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, String accountType, String authTokenType, String[] requiredFeatures, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
    Log.d("logba", "AvestAuthenticator->addAccount : ");
    final Intent intent = new Intent(context, AuthenticatorActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE, authTokenType);
    intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE, response);
    final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    if (null != options) {
        bundle.putAll(options);
    }
    bundle.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT, intent);
    return bundle;
}

@Override
public Bundle confirmCredentials(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
    Log.d("logba", "AvestAuthenticator->confirmCredentials : ");
    return null;
}

@Override
public Bundle getAuthToken(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
    if (!authTokenType.equals(AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE)) {
        final Bundle result = new Bundle();
        result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ERROR_MESSAGE, "invalid authTokenType");
        return result;
    }

    // Extract the username and password from the Account Manager, and ask
    // the server for an appropriate AuthToken.
    final AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(context);
    final String password = am.getPassword(account);
    if (password != null) {
        final String authToken = "asdasdlkwejfdoiqwjndoiwqj"; //NetworkUtilities.authenticate(account.name, password);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(authToken)) {
            final Bundle result = new Bundle();
            result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
            result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
            result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN, authToken);
            return result;
        }
    }
    final Intent intent = new Intent(context, AuthenticatorActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("username", account.name);
    intent.putExtra("authtokenType", authTokenType);
    intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE, response);
    final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT, intent);
    return bundle;
}


@Override
public String getAuthTokenLabel(String authTokenType) {
    Log.d("logba", "AvestAuthenticator->getAuthTokenLabel : ");
    return null;
}

@Override
public Bundle updateCredentials(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
    Log.d("logba", "AvestAuthenticator->updateCredentials : ");
    return null;
}

@Override
public Bundle hasFeatures(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, String[] features) throws NetworkErrorException {
    final Bundle result = new Bundle();
    result.putBoolean(AccountManager.KEY_BOOLEAN_RESULT, false);
    return result;
}

}
```

Comment: Если у вас Spring, то я могу поделиться примером на Angular и Spring.

Answer (score 1):

Делал что-то подобное:

```
class AccountAuthenticator extends AbstractAccountAuthenticator {

private Context mContext;

AccountAuthenticator(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public Bundle editProperties(AccountAuthenticatorResponse pAccountAuthenticatorResponse, String pS) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Bundle addAccount(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, String accountType, String authTokenType, String[] requiredFeatures, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
    AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(mContext);
    if (am.getAccountsByType(TOKEN_TYPE).length > 0) {
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.you_already_have_account, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        });
        return null;
    }

    final Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, BackContentActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(CONST.CONTENT_ID, ViewFactory.AUTHORIZATION_VIEW);
    intent.putExtra(IS_SYSTEM_ADD_ACCOUNT, true);
    intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE, response);
    final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT, intent);
    return bundle;
}

@Override
public Bundle confirmCredentials(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account pAccount, Bundle pBundle) throws NetworkErrorException {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Bundle getAuthToken(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle pBundle) throws NetworkErrorException {

    AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(mContext);
    String authToken = am.peekAuthToken(account, authTokenType);

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(authToken)) {
        final Bundle result = new Bundle();
        result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
        result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
        result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN, authToken);
        return result;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, BackContentActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    intent.putExtra(CONST.CONTENT_ID, ViewFactory.AUTHORIZATION_VIEW);
    intent.putExtra(IS_SYSTEM_ADD_ACCOUNT, false);
    intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
    intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE, response);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT, intent);

    return bundle;
}

@Override
public String getAuthTokenLabel(String pS) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Bundle updateCredentials(AccountAuthenticatorResponse pAccountAuthenticatorResponse, Account pAccount, String pS, Bundle pBundle) throws NetworkErrorException {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Bundle hasFeatures(AccountAuthenticatorResponse pAccountAuthenticatorResponse, Account pAccount, String[] pStrings) throws NetworkErrorException {
    return null;
}
}
```

Интерцептор для Retrofit:

```
public class AuthorizationInterceptor implements Interceptor {

private Context mContext;
private InternalRemoteRepository mRemoteRepository;
private Gson mGson;


public AuthorizationInterceptor(Context pContext, RemoteRepository pRemoteRepository, Gson pGson) {
    mContext = pContext;
    mRemoteRepository = (InternalRemoteRepository) pRemoteRepository;
    mGson = pGson;
}

@Override
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

    if (!Network.isNetworkAvailable(mContext)) {
        throw new NetworkException(mContext.getString(R.string.internet_connection_not_available));
    }

    Response response;
    try {
        response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new NetworkException(e.getMessage());
    }

    ResponseBody body = response.body();
    String bodyValue = body.string();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(bodyValue)) {
        RPCResponse result = mGson.fromJson(bodyValue, RPCResponse.class);
        if (!result.isSuccess()) {
            switch (result.getErrorCode()) {
                case ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND:
                case ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND_AUTH:
                case ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD:
                case ERROR_ACCOUNT_NOT_SUPPORT:
                    throw new AuthorizationException(result.getMessage(), result.getErrorCode());
                case ERROR_INVALID_ACCESS:
                case ERROR_ACCESS_TOKEN_NOT_FOUND:
                case ERROR_ACCESS_DIED:
                    mRemoteRepository
                            .reAuthorization()
                            .subscribe(success -> {
                                if (!success) {
                                    throw new AuthorizationException(result.getMessage(), result.getErrorCode());
                                }
                            }, pThrowable -> {
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setAction(AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE);
                                mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
                            });
                    break;
                case ERROR_REFRESH_ACCESS_TOKEN:
                    mRemoteRepository
                            .refreshToken()
                            .subscribe(success -> {
                                if (!success) {
                                    mRemoteRepository
                                            .reAuthorization()
                                            .subscribe(resuccess -> {
                                                if (!resuccess) {
                                                    throw new AuthorizationException(result.getMessage(), result.getErrorCode());
                                                }
                                            }, pThrowable -> {
                                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                                intent.setAction(AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE);
                                                mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
                                            });
                                }
                            });
                    break;
                case ERROR_INTERNAL_SERVER:
                    throw new UnknownServerException(result.getMessage());
                default:
                    throw new UnknownException(result.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    return response
            .newBuilder()
            .body(ResponseBody.create(body.contentType(), bodyValue))
            .build();
}
}
```

Связывание Manager и Interceptor:

```
  public RemoteRepositoryImpl() {
    Injector.di().inject(this);

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Calendar.class, new CalendarTypeAdapter())
            .setExclusionStrategies(new ExposeExclusionStrategy())
            .create();

    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .certificatePinner(new CertificatePinner.Builder()
                    .add(LocaleTool.getServerUrl(), BuildConfig.SERVER_CERTIFICATE_SIGNATURE).build())
            .addInterceptor(new AuthorizationInterceptor(mContext, this, gson))
            .addNetworkInterceptor(logging)
            .build();

    mService = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(LocaleTool.getServerUrl())
            .client(client)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(TokenInjectorFactory.create(mAccountManager, gson)) // TODO Ordering is important
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build()
            .create(IQshaService.class);

    BroadcastReceiver failureReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            client.dispatcher().cancelAll();
        }
    };
    mContext.registerReceiver(failureReceiver, new IntentFilter(AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE));
}

@Override
public Observable<Boolean> authorization(String login, String password) {
    return Observable.create(e -> mService
            .authorization(new RPCRequest<>("authorization", new Login(login, password)))
            .subscribe(resultToken -> {
                if (resultToken.isSuccess()) {
                    Token token = resultToken.getResult();

                    Account account;
                    if (mAccountManager.getAccountsByType(TOKEN_TYPE).length > 0) {
                        account = mAccountManager.getAccountsByType(TOKEN_TYPE)[0];
                    } else {
                        account = new Account(login, TOKEN_TYPE);
                        mAccountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, password, null);
                    }

                    mAccountManager.setPassword(account, password);
                    mAccountManager.setAuthToken(account, TOKEN_TYPE, token.getAccessToken());
                    mAccountManager.setUserData(account, Token.REFRESH_TOKEN, token.getRefreshToken());
                    mAccountManager.setUserData(account, Token.EXPIRES_IN, token.getExpiresIn());
                    mAccountManager.setUserData(account, Token.USER_ID, token.getGuid());
                    mAccountManager.setUserData(account, Token.TIME, SERVER_DATE_FORMAT.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));

                    e.onNext(true);
                } else e.onNext(false);
            }, e::onError));
}
```